# recurrence using (mod 2^32+1)

Tags: algorithm, math

Where m = 2^32+1 = 641*6700417 the mod function is little more than a single subtract on 32-bit processors. I don’t care that the recurrence
    `Seed = Seed*a%m`
is not a good random number generator. I wish to use it in an encryption algorithm as a 32-bit wide sbox. Is there an algorithm that would return true if a trial value of “a” would cause the recurrence to visit all 2^32 values?

Assuming that such an algorithm exits I suspect that if a*b%m = 1 then the recurrence using “b” would run backwards. Is what I suspect true. I would use “b” to implement the inverse sbox.

I can do everything I ask using mod (2^16+1) but that number is prime.

Comment: Best suited for http://crypto.stackexchange.com or http://math.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: It works because the number is prime. Mersenne primes should work otherwise it would be possible for two integers m, n such that m*n is a divisor of the modular number and would return non-unique values for the sbox and inverse sbox. In your case using 2^16 + 1 as your modular number gives you only unique values and would allow b to be used to implement the inverse sbox but only for Mersenne primes.

Comment: This is a number theory question, but the answer is "No such value exists" because |Zn˟| = (n-1) only for prime n, and it is cyclic only for certain values of n ([details in this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n)). You should follow up on http://math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an algorithm that would return true if a trial value of “a” would cause the recurrence to visit all 2<sup>32</sup> values?

Yes there is:

```
return false;
```

The most obvious reason is that the set of all 2<sup>32</sup> possible values includes the value zero, and there the recurrence gets stuck, so it isn't cyclic. But even if you exclude zero, if you start with a multiple of 641, then you will only ever visit multiples of 641, and the same holds for the other factor.

This kind of “visit all values” property only works if you reduce modulo some prime, and if you exclude zero.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very simple question. It is easy to answer that in your case the numbers you use are poor. However, the easy answer: use primes is not the correct answer, either.

If we use the recurrence:

*r* := (*r* *a*) mod *m*

it is easy to see, that this gives the maximal cycle (*m*-1) if and only if all *a*^*i* mod *m* give different numbers for *i* = 0 .. *m*-2. However, this does not automatically happen even if both *a* and *m* are primes.

An example of two primes which cannot be used: *a* = 13, *m* = 17, because 13^4 mod 17 == 1, and the cycle will be very short (4 steps).

So, we need some other requirements, as well. To make a very long story short, a generator of this type (multiplicative congruential generator) produces the maximal cycle (*m*-1) if:

- *m* is prime
- *a* is a primitive root of *m*

Unfortunately, the latter requirement is a bit difficult, as there is no general formula to find primitive roots. (And please note that a does not have to be a prime, for example the combination *m*=17 and *a*=10 gives the full cycle.)

So, despite this being a seemingly simple problem, it touches some rather fundamental aspects of number theory.